# How to copy bits from one variable to another?

Tags: c++, c, variables, copy, bit-manipulation

Let's say I have this `int` variable `v1`:

```
1100 1010
```

And this variable `int v2`:

```
1001 1110
```

I need to copy the last four bits from `v2` to the last four bits of `v1` so that the result is:

```
1100 1110
^    ^ last four bits of v2
|
| first four bits of v1
```

How would I got about doing this in C or C++? I read a few articles about bitwise operations but I couldn't find any information specifically about this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Bitwise operations were the right things to look for.

```
v1 = (v1 & ~0xf) | (v2 & 0xf);
```

Is there something specific you didn't understand from the articles you read?

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
v1 = (v1 & 0xf0) | (v2 & 0xf);
```

If the value of "v1" has more bits, you'd want to use a bigger mask:

```
v1 = (v1 & 0xfffffff0) | (v2 & 0xf);
```

Answer (score 3):

The most readable way to write it, in my opinion:

```
v1 &= ~0x0F;       // clear least sig. nibble of v1
v1 |= v2 & 0x0F;   // copy least sig. nibble of v2 into v1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
v1 = (v2 & 0x0F) | (v1 & 0xF0);
```